# Convert international phone number into local one

Tags: java, android, phone-number, libphonenumber

I'm trying to use `libphonenumber` google library to convert a number from
international to local.

The international number represent is: "+97239658320"

The local number (here in Israel is): "039658320"

http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

```
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

    PhoneNumber phone = null;

    try
    {
        phone = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().parse("+97239658320", null);
    }

    catch (NumberParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

however, in "phone" the results are:

```
Country Code: 972 National Number: 39658320 (without the leading zero)
```

how do I convert it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the quick example of the [project page](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) says that you after parsing should have:

```
{
country_code: 972
national_number: 39658320
}
```

To get it in your desired format you should format it with format `NATIONAL`:

```
phoneUtil.format(phone, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL)
```

To strip out any phone number separators take a look at [stripSeparators()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#stripSeparators%28java.lang.String%29) from [android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html)

Comment: thanks! the result is now: 03-965-8320. I'll remove the hyphens manually :D